# Does the total variation of a function bound its numerical integration error, much like its first derivative?

Tags: numerical-methods, integration, bounded-variation

When estimating the convergence of a Riemann sum to its integral, or equivalently the error in numerical integration, the commonly used bound is by upper bounding it's first derivative (see, for example the [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Conservative_.28a_priori.29_error_estimation) on wikipedia).

Specifically, the inequality

$\left| \int_a^b f(x)\,dx - (b - a) f(a) \right| \leq {(b - a)^2 \over 2} \sup_{a \leq x \leq b} \left| f'(x) \right|$

implies that the error $E_{n}$ of an $n$ term Riemann sum is bounded by

$E_n \leq \frac{1}{2n}\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} \left| f'(x) \right|$

However, this is seemingly poor if the maximum of the first derivative is very peaked.  A smooth step function, for example, would have Riemann sum converging faster than the bound suggests: consider the separately the subsets of the domain where the first derivative is small and large, and add the errors together.  In the former subset you may use a smaller maximum for the derivative.

My question is about improving this to use the [total variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) of the function $f$ instead of the derivative.  Intuitively if the function has large derivative --- but only briefly, like the step function --- then this should be evident from its total variation.  Is such a bound possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m \le f \le M$ on $[a,b]$, $m(b-a) \le \int_a^b f(x) \ dx \le M(b-a)$, and $(b-a) f(t)$
satisfies the same bounds for any $t \in [a,b]$.  Thus $|\int_a^b f(x)\ dx - (b-a) f(t)| \le (M-m)(b-a) \le (b-a) V_a^b(f)$.  Adding this up for $n$ intervals $[a_{j-1},a_j]$
in a Riemann sum we get
$$E_n \le \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n V_{a_{j-1}}^{a_j}(f) = \frac{b-a}{n} V_a^b(f)$$